# Flutter - how to close popup screen if stream returns no data/empty array

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder

In my Flutter app I have a pop up screen that can be opened if a stream returns data

The pop up form itself displays a list of entries from the same stream.  Is it possible to have the pop up screen close itself if the stream has no data?

Basically,  I want to call ...

```
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

.. if within the pop up screen the stream returns no data or an empty array,  but where would I inject this call?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend listening to the stream maybe on an initState. So you can dispose of it when you go back.

Comment: Not sure that I follow.   To explain further.  My app has main screen ‘A’.  Within this main screen a button will appear if the stream has data array of length greater than zero.  Clicking on this button will open up pop up screen ‘B’.  The screen B displays a list of items found in the stream, using a stream builder.   As outside events can change the same source data, the list contents will change and it’s possible for the stream to have no data when screen B is open. What I want is for screen B to automatically close if the stream has no data.